# Check if listbox item exist from textbox value

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Method that checks if listbox item exists:

```
    private bool ValueAlreadyInListLanguage(object vItem)
    {
        string valueTextBox = TextBoxLanguages.Text;
        string valueListBox = vItem.ToString();

        return valueTextBox == valueListBox;
    }
```

[image]

**SOLUTION**

```
    private bool ValueAlreadyInListLanguage(object vItem)
    {
        string valueTextBox = TextBoxLanguages.Text.Trim();
        string valueListBox = vItem.ToString();

        return valueTextBox.Equals(valueListBox, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Now if i save for example "Swedish" to my listbox, i cannot add "swedish" because it already exists.

Comment: You know that 'Swedish' and 'swedish' are different?

Comment: @Tomtom, Ofcourse i know, but i don't really know how to make the method to understand it..

Comment: @Kriistiian, if you know then go with below answers..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative fix  without uppercasing or lowercasing would be:

```
return valueTextBox.Equals(valueListBox,String.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

I'd also put a trim in here:

```
string valueTextBox = TextBoxLanguages.Text.Trim();
```

Because white space at the end of the entered text will spoil the equality.

i.e. "Swedish " != "Swedish"

Comment: both your and coolmines answer is right, but this one is better, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
private bool ValueAlreadyInListLanguage(object vItem)
{
    string valueTextBox = textBox1.Text;
    string valueListBox = vItem.ToString();

    return valueTextBox.Equals(valueListBox, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: This one is the right one and it works now. If i add Swedish to the listbox i cannot add "swedish" with lower case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your comparison:

```
return valueTextBox.ToLower() == valueListBox.ToLower();
```

As someone pointed out in the comment - `Swedish` is not equal to `swedish` - it recognizes letter case.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private bool ValueAlreadyInListLanguage(object vItem)
{
   return TextBoxLanguages.Text.ToLower().Equals(vItem.ToString().ToLower());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing below

```
    string valueTextBox = TextBoxLanguages.Text.ToUpper();
    string valueListBox = vItem.ToString().ToUpper();
```